# Electron ipc messages are not received

Tags: javascript, webview, ipc, electron

I'm making my app with GitHub's Electron. My index.html has an embedded script called renderer.js and index.html also dynamically loads another html file called module.html and within module.html there is a webview. The webview utilizes a preloader. I am trying to send ipc messages between renderer.js and preloader.js.

I have a console.log on the send portion (in the renderer.js) and the receive portion (in the preloader.js). Only the console.log for the send works and I get nothing on the receiving end. Devtron also shows nothing. And I do have separate consoles for both the webview and the index.html.

preloader.js

```
window.__devtron = {require: require, process: process}
require('devtron').install();

const { ipcRenderer: ipc } = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

ipc.on('show-dialog', (event, {type}) => {
  console.log('please receive this '+type); //THIS CONSOLE LOG DOES NOT WORK
});

});
```

renderer.js

```
window.__devtron = {require: require, process: process}
require('devtron').install();

const { ipcRenderer: ipc, remote } = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  const webview = document.getElementById('webview');
  const btn = document.getElementById('devtools');
  const btn2 = document.getElementById('execjs');
  btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('clicked'); //THIS CONSOLELOG WORKS
    ipc.send('show-dialog', {
    type: 'info'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: As the [documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/) shows, Electron's IPC module is only intended to send messages between ipcRenderer and ipcMain, not ipcRenderer <> ipcRenderer.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. How do you recommend sending efficient messages between two renderer processes?

Comment: I recommend [Electron Window Manager](https://github.com/TamkeenLMS/electron-window-manager) as it lets you share data between all created windows, what IPC is basically for.